# Waves and Alternating Current

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electric-current

What will happen if a metallic spring fixed at one end which is connected to a steel wire of certain length and the other end of the steel wire is connected to an AC source. Shall we see the spring expanding? Or will standing waves will be generated? If so, please explain why and how will this happen? I personally am awestruck by the idea that the spring will expand. Any answer will be of great help.

Comment: The AC source needs at least two connections---what is the AC ground connected to?

Comment: Well that was the question which my professor  posed. But we can take it to be a complete circuit with a spring in middle.